Quill Editor add validation to links
I am trying to add url validation within the quill editor on my webapp.
I have successfully achieved this when user's are simply adding a link to some text, but this isn't working when they try to add text, at least not properly.
The following code is what allowed me to achieve this, I can't include everything but I hope this is enough.
...
this.editor = new Quill(this.$refs.editor, quillSettings)
...
this.editor.getModule('toolbar').handlers.link = this.handleLink.bind(this.editor.getModule('toolbar'))
this.editor.theme.tooltip.save = this.validateAndSaveLink.bind(this)
...
/**
 * Validates that links are valid URls that start with `http` or `https`
 * Otherwise an alert is shown
 */
validateAndSaveLink() {
  const tooltip = this.editor.theme.tooltip
  const linkInput = tooltip.root.querySelector('input[data-link]')
  const { value } = linkInput
  if (tooltip.root.getAttribute('data-mode') === 'link') {
    if (!this.URL_REGEX.test(value)) {
      alert('Please enter a valid URL.')
      return
    }
    const { scrollTop } = this.editor.root
    if (this.linkRange) {
      this.editor.formatText(this.linkRange, 'link', value, 'user')
      delete this.linkRange
    } else {
      this.editor.focus()
      this.editor.format('link', value, 'user')
    }
    this.editor.root.scrollTop = scrollTop
  }
  linkInput.value = ''
  tooltip.hide()
},

/**
 * This function is binded to the quill toolbar and overrides the validation functionality of the input for links
 */
handleLink(value) {
  const quill = this.editor
  if (!value) {
    quill.format('link', false)
  } else {
    const range = quill.getSelection()
    if (!range || range.length === 0) {
      return
    }
    let preview = quill.getText(range)
    const { tooltip } = quill.theme
    tooltip.save = this.validateAndSaveLink.bind(this)
    tooltip.edit('link', preview)
  }
},

So, adding a link to text is completely fine, you can save it, but if my regex is not satisfied, an alert is shown.
However, in the Quill editor, you can click some linked text, and it shows a preview as well as the option to edit, or remove the link.
If I then edit the link here, changing it to some other valid link and press save, the link is not actually updated and still points to the previous link. If you try to click the linked text again, it throws an error:
quill.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: l.position is not a function
    at t.value (quill.min.js:8:63520)
    at t.value (quill.min.js:8:25056)
    at e.<anonymous> (quill.min.js:8:214681)
    at o.emit (quill.min.js:8:143547)
    at e.value (quill.min.js:8:32595)
    at t.value (quill.min.js:8:67932)
    at quill.min.js:8:62344
    at quill.min.js:8:32846
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.value (quill.min.js:8:32761)

I appreciate this may not be enough to go of, but any help would be great.
